# Where is it established that Hikaru Sulu was born in San Francisco?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I seem to remember (and [Memory Alpha agrees](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hikaru_Sulu)) that Sulu was born in San Francisco.

Which episode or movie (or book) establishes this? I can't find the on-screen source.

Comment: Memory Alpha literally lists the sources for the opening statements, so all you had to do was Ctrl+F for "San Francisco" in their transcripts.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### In Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home

> KIRK: Where would we find these reactors, ...theoretically?
>
> SPOCK: Nuclear power was widely used in naval vessels.
>
> [now in "Bird-of-Prey bridge"]
>
> **SULU: San Francisco. I was born there.**
>
> MCCOY: It doesn't look all that different.
>
> KIRK: Set us down in Golden Gate Park.

Although I have used the script search, it is also stated in [San Francisco Memory Alpha article](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/San_Francisco) as the leading quote.

Answer (score 3):

In ["The Kobayashi Maru"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kobayashi_Maru_(Star_Trek_novel))

While stranded in a damaged shuttlecraft, Kirk, Sulu, Chekov, and Scotty recall their Starfleet Academy Command School experiences with the simulation scenario The Kobayashi Maru. Within the narrative of his story, Sulu describes his grandfather making a thousand paper cranes which are released on to the water near their family home in San Francisco Bay.

Comment: the novels aren't generally considered to be an official canon source (nor is it an 'on-screen source' as the question asked for. Additionally, that book was written a few years after Star Trek IV (which references SF as his birthplace)

Comment: Canon schmanon. Trek is Trek, and the OP actually asks for episode / movie / book having NOT FOUND an on-screen source.

Comment: good point as to my incorrect reference to the OP - I'd edit the comment if I could :)

Comment: Schmanon is illogical, and definitely not an 'on-screen' source. Also "Trek is Trek" is a tautology, and also logically irrelevant.

Comment: _"Canon schmanon"_ No!

Comment: Unless you can provide a quote, we can only guess that his family home is located in the same place where he was born, which is not always the case.

Comment: @edmund That's a fair point - I'll dig out my dog-eared and much-loved copy later and transcribe the passage.